# How to create a CRUD API on Amazon Lambda using Micronaut

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, micronaut

I want to create a CRUD API using Micronaut and deploy it on AWS Lambda, exposing the different methods with Amazon API Gateway. I could create different Kotlin Projects per endpoint (GET, POST...), one including one function, but that's kind of cumbersome so I'd rather have a single project with all the CRUD functions.

My current application contains two functions: one Supplier (GET) and one Consumer (POST).

**Application:**

```
object Application {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            Micronaut.build()
                    .packages("micronaut.aws.poc")
                    .mainClass(Application.javaClass)
                    .start()
        }
}
```

**Supplier:**

```
@FunctionBean("micronaut-aws-poc")
class MicronautAwsPocFunction : Supplier<String> {

    override fun get(): String {
        println("GET")
        return "micronaut-aws-poc"
    }
}
```

**Consumer:**

```
@FunctionBean("micronaut-aws-poc-post")
class MicronautAwsPocPostFunction : Consumer<String> {

    override fun accept(t: String) {
        println("POST $t")
    }

}
```

Then, I have created a resource in Amazon API Gateway with one GET and one POST method. The problem is, no matter which one I call, the MicronautAwsPocFunction is always invoked.

1. Is it possible/recommended to embed many functions in a single jar?
2. How can I make POST invocations call the MicronautAwsPocPostFunction instead of the MicronautAwsPocFunction?
3. In case I wanted an additional PUT function, how could I model it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a different approach, this is how I solved it:

Instead of using functions I changed to [Lambda Functions Using AWS API Gateway Proxy](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.1.0.M1/guide/index.html#writingFunctions). Also take into account [this specific aws lambda documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aws/latest/guide/index.html#apiProxy).

I recreated the project with this command `mn create-app micronaut-poc --features aws-api-gateway -l kotlin`

Now I have a "normal" REST application with two controllers:

```
@Controller("/")
class PingController {

    @Get("/")
    fun index(): String {
        return "{\"pong\":true}"
    }
}

@Controller("/")
class PongController {

    @Post("/")
    fun post(): String {
        println("PONG!!!!!!!")
        return "{\"ping\":true}"
    }
}
```

The magic happens in the AWS API Gateway configuration. We have to configure a proxy resource:

[image]

Finally we can invoke the lambda from the API Gateway setting the correct HTTP Method. **IMPORTANT:** Set a host header, otherwise Micronaut will throw a nullpointerexception:

GET:

[image]

POST:

[image]